HTML element button - 'onclick' attribute issues, multiple functions
I have issues with my 'onclick' attribute on HTML element 'button'. I want to start JS scripts whenever this button is clicked.
I'm using few JS scripts to get input value and my button is there to regenerate the input value. First JS script that I'm using to create input value is:
function makerandomstring(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
var textforHash = makerandomstring(20);
console.log(textforHash);

(With this JS function, I'm creating random string with 20 characters and saved it in variable called 'textforHash'.)
This function comes next:
function sha256(ascii) {
    function rightRotate(value, amount) {
        return (value>>>amount) | (value<<(32 - amount));
    };
    
    var mathPow = Math.pow;
    var maxWord = mathPow(2, 32);
    var lengthProperty = 'length'
    var i, j;
    var result = ''
  
    var words = [];
    var asciiBitLength = ascii[lengthProperty]*8;
    
    var hash = sha256.h = sha256.h || [];
    var k = sha256.k = sha256.k || [];
    var primeCounter = k[lengthProperty];
  
    var isComposite = {};
    for (var candidate = 2; primeCounter < 64; candidate++) {
        if (!isComposite[candidate]) {
            for (i = 0; i < 313; i += candidate) {
                isComposite[i] = candidate;
            }
            hash[primeCounter] = (mathPow(candidate, .5)*maxWord)|0;
            k[primeCounter++] = (mathPow(candidate, 1/3)*maxWord)|0;
        }
    }
    
    ascii += '\x80'
    while (ascii[lengthProperty]%64 - 56) ascii += '\x00' 
    for (i = 0; i < ascii[lengthProperty]; i++) {
        j = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
        if (j>>8) return; 
        words[i>>2] |= j << ((3 - i)%4)*8;
    }
    words[words[lengthProperty]] = ((asciiBitLength/maxWord)|0);
    words[words[lengthProperty]] = (asciiBitLength)
    
    for (j = 0; j < words[lengthProperty];) {
        var w = words.slice(j, j += 16); 
        var oldHash = hash;
        hash = hash.slice(0, 8);
        
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            var i2 = i + j;
            var w15 = w[i - 15], w2 = w[i - 2];
            var a = hash[0], e = hash[4];
            var temp1 = hash[7]
                + (rightRotate(e, 6) ^ rightRotate(e, 11) ^ rightRotate(e, 25)) // S1
                + ((e&hash[5])^((~e)&hash[6])) // ch
                + k[i]
                + (w[i] = (i < 16) ? w[i] : (
                        w[i - 16]
                        + (rightRotate(w15, 7) ^ rightRotate(w15, 18) ^ (w15>>>3)) // s0
                        + w[i - 7]
                        + (rightRotate(w2, 17) ^ rightRotate(w2, 19) ^ (w2>>>10)) // s1
                    )|0
                );
            var temp2 = (rightRotate(a, 2) ^ rightRotate(a, 13) ^ rightRotate(a, 22)) // S0
                + ((a&hash[1])^(a&hash[2])^(hash[1]&hash[2])); // maj
            
            hash = [(temp1 + temp2)|0].concat(hash);
            hash[4] = (hash[4] + temp1)|0;
        }
        
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            hash[i] = (hash[i] + oldHash[i])|0;
        }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 3; j + 1; j--) {
            var b = (hash[i]>>(j*8))&255;
            result += ((b < 16) ? 0 : '') + b.toString(16);
        }
    }
    return result;
  };

(With this function, I am creating SHA-256 hash of previously created random string.)
And this is coming for the end:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const saveHash = sha256(textforHash);
    document.getElementById('sha256hash').value = saveHash;
    console.log(saveHash);
  });

(With this script, I'm pasting function result into HTML element 'input (type="text"), and displaying it in console so I can validate that SHA256 hash is matching with random string created.)
Here is my code in HTML on this div:
<div class="sha256hash_bar_grid">
  <input class="sha256_hash" type="text" id="sha256hash" readonly>
  <button class="sha256_hash_regenerate" onclick="">Regenerate</button>
</div>

Can someone help me, when I click this button 'Regenerate' I want to regenerate all my functions so new value is pasted in input! Thanks in advance.

onclick="" you'll need to put something there if you wish to call a function - which function did you want to call

I know that, but creating new input value is 3-step process - 1st step is making random string, 2nd step is creating SHA256 hash of it, and 3rd step is putting the value in HTML. The problem is that I don't know how to call these 3 functions in HTML when button 'Regenerate' is pressed.

create a function that does the required steps. You can then call it

So you are suggesting that I should paste all my functions into 1 seperate .js file and call just that function? It should be working then?

no, I am not. I said "create a function that does the steps required, and call that function in onclick ... or, better, use addEventListener (but that's not important, using onclick is fine for you)

@jordimetil btw are you familiar with "accepting" an answer? You've asked quite a few questions, but not accepted any answers.

Not really, thanks for mentioning. Gonna start using it :)

Create a new function, e.g. regenerateOnClick(), to call from your html button code.
Also, replace the code in your DOMContentLoaded event listener with just a call to this new function.
Remove the global textforHash variable, it is no longer needed.
Run the snippet below, to see the working changes:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // NOTE Just call the new function
  regenerateOnClick( );
});

// New function
function regenerateOnClick( ) {
  let textforHash = makerandomstring(20);
  console.log(`textforHash: ${textforHash}`);

  const saveHash = sha256(textforHash);
  document.getElementById('sha256hash').value = saveHash;
  console.log(`saveHash: ${saveHash}`);
}

function makerandomstring(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}


function sha256(ascii) {
  function rightRotate(value, amount) {
    return (value>>>amount) | (value<<(32 - amount));
  }
  
  var mathPow = Math.pow;
  var maxWord = mathPow(2, 32);
  var lengthProperty = 'length'
  var i, j;
  var result = ''
  
  var words = [];
  var asciiBitLength = ascii[lengthProperty]*8;
  
  var hash = sha256.h = sha256.h || [];
  var k = sha256.k = sha256.k || [];
  var primeCounter = k[lengthProperty];
  
  var isComposite = {};
  for (var candidate = 2; primeCounter < 64; candidate++) {
    if (!isComposite[candidate]) {
      for (i = 0; i < 313; i += candidate) {
        isComposite[i] = candidate;
      }
      hash[primeCounter] = (mathPow(candidate, 0.5)*maxWord)|0;
      k[primeCounter++] = (mathPow(candidate, 1/3)*maxWord)|0;
    }
  }
  
  ascii += '\x80'
  while (ascii[lengthProperty]%64 - 56) ascii += '\x00'
  for (i = 0; i < ascii[lengthProperty]; i++) {
    j = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
    if (j>>8) return;
    words[i>>2] |= j << ((3 - i)%4)*8;
  }
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = ((asciiBitLength/maxWord)|0);
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = (asciiBitLength)
  
  for (j = 0; j < words[lengthProperty];) {
    var w = words.slice(j, j += 16);
    var oldHash = hash;
    hash = hash.slice(0, 8);
    
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      var i2 = i + j;
      var w15 = w[i - 15], w2 = w[i - 2];
      var a = hash[0], e = hash[4];
      var temp1 = hash[7]
      + (rightRotate(e, 6) ^ rightRotate(e, 11) ^ rightRotate(e, 25)) // S1
      + ((e&hash[5])^((~e)&hash[6])) // ch
      + k[i]
      + (w[i] = (i < 16) ? w[i] : (
        w[i - 16]
        + (rightRotate(w15, 7) ^ rightRotate(w15, 18) ^ (w15>>>3)) // s0
        + w[i - 7]
        + (rightRotate(w2, 17) ^ rightRotate(w2, 19) ^ (w2>>>10)) // s1
      )|0
    );
    var temp2 = (rightRotate(a, 2) ^ rightRotate(a, 13) ^ rightRotate(a, 22)) // S0
    + ((a&hash[1])^(a&hash[2])^(hash[1]&hash[2])); // maj
    
    hash = [(temp1 + temp2)|0].concat(hash);
    hash[4] = (hash[4] + temp1)|0;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      hash[i] = (hash[i] + oldHash[i])|0;
    }
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (j = 3; j + 1; j--) {
      var b = (hash[i]>>(j*8))&255;
      result += ((b < 16) ? 0 : '') + b.toString(16);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
.sha256hash_bar_grid {
  display: grid;
}
.sha256hash_bar_grid button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
}
<div class="sha256hash_bar_grid">
  <input class="sha256_hash" type="text" id="sha256hash" readonly>
  <button class="sha256_hash_regenerate" onclick="regenerateOnClick()">Regenerate</button>
</div>



